# Group records in Master but want count for Details

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda, linq-to-entities

Please consider these tables:

Master:

```
Id              Year               Season                 Flag           City
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1               2020                 1                    8000           Paris
2               2020                 1                    7000           Paris
3               2020                 1                    9000           London
4               2020                 2                    3000           Tokyo
5               2020                 2                    1000           Paris
6               2020                 3                    2000           Tokyo 
7               2020                 1                    1000           London
8               2019                 4                    8000           Paris
9               2019                 4                    2000           Paris
```

Details:

```
 Id              MasterId                Year            Season             CurrentFlag
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1                   8                   2020              1                    8000   
 2                   9                   2020              1                    2500  
 3                   8                   2020              2                    8100
 4                   1                   2020              2                    8000
 5                   2                   2020              2                    7500
 6                   2                   2020              3                    7500
 7                   3                   2020              2                    6000
 8                   4                   2020              3                    5000
 9                   7                   2020              2                    4000
```

Consider `Master` as beginning of life-cycle of my records and `Details` for showing `CurrentFlag` in seasons. Now I want a `Linq` query that bring this result for `(Year == 2010 and Season == 1)`:

```
City      (Count Master All)  (Count Master Flag<8000) (Count Details All)  (Count Details Current Flag<8000)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Paris          2                       1                     2                    1
London         1                       1                     0                    0
```

I wrote this query:

```
var Records = (from m in master
                    join d in details
                       on m.Id equals d.MasterId into outerJoin
                    from d in outerJoin
                    where (m.Year == year && m.Dore == dore) ||
                          (d.Year == year && d.Dore == dore)
                     group m by new { m.City } into grp            <--------
                     select new
                     {
                            City = grp.Key.City,
                            Count_Master_All = grp.Count(),
                            Count_Master_Below_8000 = grp.Where(o => o.Flag < 8000),
                            Count_Details_All = ???
                            Count_Details_Below_8000 = ???                                       
                      }).ToList();
```

First problem is I only can group records with `m` and so I can't count desire records for detail table. How I can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do the Group later in query

```
var Records = (from m in master
               join d in details
                 on m.Id equals d.MasterId into outerJoin
               from d in outerJoin
               where (m.Year == year && m.Dore == dore) ||
                     (d.Year == year && d.Dore == dore)
               select new {m = m, d = d})
               .GroupBy(x => new { x.m.City })
               .Select(grp => new
               {
                  City = grp.Key.City,
                  Count_Master_All = grp.Count(),
                  Count_Master_Below_8000 = grp.Where(o => o.Flag < 8000),
                  Count_Details_All = grp.Count()                                      
               }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks but what about `Count_Details_Below_8000`?

Comment: It would be something like this : Count_Details_All = grp.Where(d => d.CurrentFlag < 8000)